# creating an :after element/div

Tags: html, css

I want to create a bottom bar underneath my h3 title. I don't want to use border-bottom due to it's lack of adjustment features. I also don't have full control on when the h3 title is created so I can't a div underneath in my html.

what I am trying to us is

CSS

```
.page-widgt h3 {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #42b4c4;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 0 30px 15px 0;
}

.page-widgt h3:after {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

but nothing is showing up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `content:""` for the `:after`

```
.page-widgt h3:after {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  content:"";
}
```

Comment: Reason simply is that your after pseudo element _is_ actually present without, but collapsed. Which is why you cannot see it.